# Error in synchronisation with monerod

Tags: monerod, synchronization, error-log

I had a problem with the synchronisation of monerod because when starting, it gives me this error:
--log-level 2

```
`2017-05-26 01:45:42.857 7f49065b6740 INFO net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:545 Binding on 0.0.0.0:18080

2017-05-26 01:45:42.859 7f49065b6740 ERROR net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:740 Exception at [boosted_tcp_server::init_server], what=bind: Address already in use

2017-05-26 01:45:42.859 7f49065b6740 ERROR net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:547 Failed to bind server

2017-05-26 01:45:42.860 7f49065b6740 INFO global src/daemon/core.h:89 Deinitializing core...

2017-05-26 01:45:42.860 7f49065b6740 DEBUG miner src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:325 Not mining - nothing to stop

2017-05-26 01:45:42.861 7f49065b6740 INFO txpool src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:763 Received signal to deactivate memory pool store

2017-05-26 01:45:42.861 7f49065b6740 INFO txpool src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:767 Memory pool store already empty

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 ERROR daemon src/daemon/core.h:94 Failed to deinitialize core...

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 DEBUG miner src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:325 Not mining - nothing to stop

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 INFO global src/daemon/protocol.h:77 Stopping cryptonote protocol...

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 INFO global src/daemon/protocol.h:81 Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 INFO msgwriter src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94 Daemon stopped successfully
Daemon stopped successfully

2017-05-26 01:45:42.862 7f49065b6740 ERROR daemon src/daemon/main.cpp:288 Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
```

`
Thank you

Comment: I had a problem with the synchronisation of monerod because when starting, it gives me this error 39:19.169 14596 FATAL net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:1062 Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2020-02-15 20:39:19.170 14596 INFO global src/daemon/core.h:94 Deinitializing core...
2020-02-15 20:39:19.229 14596 INFO global src/daemon/protocol.h:75 Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2020-02-15 20:39:19.230 14596 INFO global src/daemon/protocol.h:79 Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2020-02-15 20:39:19.231 14596 ERROR daemon src/daemon/main.cpp:339

Answer (score 5):

The second line of the log indicates `Address already in use`, which means that the address the daemon is trying to use (0.0.0.0:18080) is already used by some other sofware on your machine. As if there was already a monerod daemon running.